# Join not filtering correctly

Tags: sql

I'm struggling getting this query to display the correct data.

```
SELECT a.ReportDate
    ,a.ClientName
    ,count(a.ADUsername) AS UserCount
    ,sum(b.ShareData + b.UserData) AS DataUsage
    ,sum(d.UsedSpace) AS SQLUsage
FROM TableA AS a
    JOIN TableB AS b
        ON a.ClientName = b.ClientName AND a.ReportDate = b.ReportDate
    JOIN TableC AS c
        ON a.ClientName = c.ClientName AND b.ClientName = c.ClientName
    JOIN TableD AS d
        ON c.SQLInstance = d.ServerInstance AND a.ReportDate = d.ReportDate
WHERE a.ClientName = @client AND a.ReportDate = @date
GROUP BY a.ReportDate,a.ClientName
```

The columns display, but the data inside of them is incorrect. Specifically the UserCount, DataUsage, and SQLUsage column has numbers much larger than it should. To recap what is happening:

TableA contains a list of names and I need a count of those names for a specified date.
TableB contains 2 columns of numerical data that needs to be match the same clientname and date from TableA.
TableC is informational data for each clientname in TableA and Table B.
TableD has more columns of numerical data that need to match the instance name from TableC that matches the clientname from TableA and TableB as well as the report date.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here are the results of this query:

```
ReportDate | ClientName | UserCount | DataUsage | SqlUsage
03/09/2017 | Client | 175 | 125531.00 | 168816.20
```

If I do a JOIN on Table A and B, I get the correct data.

```
SELECT a.ReportDate,a.ClientName
    ,count(a.ADUsername) AS UserCount
    ,sum(b.ShareData + b.UserData) AS DataUsage
FROM TableAs AS a
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS b
        ON a.ClientName = b.ClientName
WHERE a.ClientName = @client AND a.ReportDate = @date
GROUP BY a.ReportDate,a.ClientName
```

Returns:

```
ReportDate | ClientName | UserCount | DataUsage
03/09/2017 | Client | 7 | 5021.24
```

Then doing the sum for SQLUsage

```
SELECT sum(UsedSpace)
FROM TableD
WHERE ServerInstance = @instance AND ReportDate = @date
```

Gives me `24116.60`

All of that information is correct.

Comment: Even if it's not exactly right, @Psi's answer is surely on the right track.  You're unlikely to get a better one without providing some sample data that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what is going on here:

You want to get a report for a specific client (= host) that has multiple users. Each of them generate a single row in tables A and B.

So when there are 5 users on that machine, you select ALL users from table A and cross them with ALL users in table B, making a total of 25 combinations (you only match the clientName and the reportDate, but if there are more than 1 user, they multiply).

Also, you count the used space for the whole machine, but this one is fetched for every user found on that machine squared. So of course this value is too big either.

You

- should ensure that one row in table A really matches only one row in table B
- should ensure that you count the used space for the machine only *once* (or sum up the space used by a single user from tables A and B)
- should remove one of the two conditions `ON a.ClientName = c.ClientName AND b.ClientName = c.ClientName`, because in the first join you define that A.clientName = B.clientName. So you only need to compare one of them with c.clientName (it's a mathematical axiom, if a=b and b=c then a=c)

Comment: When I do a JOIN on table's A and B I get the correct data. it's when I add C and D that everything breaks down.

Comment: Maybe you want to post your table schema and some example data?